# CakePHP2 testing login()

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, phpunit, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I want to test the login() action in my UsersController.php

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $helpers = array('Html', 'Form');
    public $components = array('RequestHandler');

    public function beforeFilter() {
        parent::beforeFilter();
        $this->Auth->allow('logout', 'login');
        // $this->Auth->allow('logout');
        $this->Security->csrfExpires = '+1 hour';
    }

    public function login() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            if ($this->Auth->login()) {
                return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('Invalid username or password, try again'),'info');
            }
        }
    }
```

The AppController.php

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    public $components  = array(
        'Session',
        'Security',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'dashboards', 'action' => 'welcome'),
            'authorize' => array('Controller')
        )
    );

    public function isAuthorized($user) {
        //Admin can access every action
        if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 'admin') {
            return true;
        }

        //Default deny
        $this->Session->setFlash('You are not allowed to access the requested page');
        return false;
    }

}
```

The UsersControllerTest.php

```
<?php

class UsersControllerTest extends ControllerTestCase {
    public $autoRender = false;
    public $fixtures = array('app.user','app.account');

    public function setUp() {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->User = ClassRegistry::init('User');
    }

...snip...
    public function testLogin() {

        $this->Users = $this->generate('Users', array(
            'components' => array(
                //'Session',
                'Security' => array('_validatePost'),
            )
        ));
        $this->Users->Security->expects($this->any())
             ->method('_validatePost')
             ->will($this->returnValue(true));

        $user = array();
        $user['User']['username'] = 'admin';
        //$user['User']['password'] = Security::hash('test', null, true);
        $user['User']['password'] = 'test';

        $result = $this->testAction('/users/login',
            array('data' => $user, 'method' => 'post', 'return' => 'contents')
        );

        debug( $this->contents); 
        //OUTPUTS: I get "Invalid username or password, try again"
        //EXPECTED: A successful login message since I provided the correct credentials

    }
```

<strike>So, how would I test my login() method when the `$this->testAction('/users/login', array('data' => $user, 'method' => 'post', 'return' => 'contents'));` returns nothing?</strike>

**OUTPUTS:** I get "Invalid username or password, try again"

**EXPECTED:** A successful login message since I provided the correct credentials

Any reply would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to @jeremyharris I was able to test my login()

UsersControllerTest.php

```
public function testLogin() {
    $this->Users = $this->generate('Users', array(
        'components' => array(
            'Security' => array('_validatePost'),
        )
    ));

    $data = array();
    $data['User']['username'] = 'admin';
    $data['User']['password'] = 'test';

    $this->Users->Auth->logout();
    $this->testAction('/users/login',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post', 'return' => 'contents')
    );

    $result = $this->testAction('/',
        array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'contents')
    );

    // debug($result); 
    $this->assertContains('You are logged in as: <span class="label">admin</span>',$result);
}

public function testLoginInvalid() {
    $this->Users = $this->generate('Users', array(
        'components' => array(
            'Security' => array('_validatePost'),
        )
    ));

    $data = array();
    $data['User']['username'] = 'admin';
    $data['User']['password'] = 'BLAH!';

    $this->Users->Auth->logout();
    $this->testAction('/users/login',
        array('data' => $data, 'method' => 'post', 'return' => 'contents')
    );

    $result = $this->testAction('/users/login',
        array('method' => 'get', 'return' => 'contents')
    );

    // debug($result); 
    $this->assertNotContains('You are logged in as',$result);
    $this->assertContains('id="UserLoginForm" method="post"',$result);
}
```

UserFixture.php, I used the init() method - as @jeremyharris said regarding the hashed passwords.

```
<?php
App::uses('AuthComponent', 'Controller/Component');

class UserFixture extends CakeTestFixture {
    /* Optional. Set this property to load fixtures to a different test datasource */
    public $useDbConfig = 'test';

    public $fields = array(
        'id' => array('type' => 'integer', 'key' => 'primary'),
        'account_id' => array('type' => 'integer'),
        'username' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'email' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'password' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'password_token' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'password_token_expiry' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 255, 'null' => false),
        'role' => array('type' => 'string', 'length' => 25, 'null' => false),
        'created' => 'datetime',
        'modified' => 'datetime'
    );

/*    public $records = array(
        array('id'=>1, 'account_id' => 1, 'username' => 'admin', 'email' => 'admin@test.com', 'password' => 'f57f702f8d557ae5318fa49455cbe9838c1d1712', 'role' => 'admin', 'password_token'=>'', 'password_token_expiry'=>'','created' => '2012-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2012-03-18 10:41:31'),
        array('id'=>2, 'account_id' => 1, 'username' => 'user', 'email' => 'user@test.com', 'password' => 'f57f702f8d557ae5318fa49455cbe9838c1d1712', 'role' => 'user', 'password_token'=>'', 'password_token_expiry'=>'', 'created' => '2012-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2012-03-18 10:41:31')
    );
*/
     public function init() {
        $this->records = array(
            array('id'=>1, 'account_id' => 1, 'username' => 'admin', 'email' => 'admin@test.com', 'password' => AuthComponent::password('test'), 'role' => 'admin', 'password_token'=>'', 'password_token_expiry'=>'','created' => '2012-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2012-03-18 10:41:31'),
            array('id'=>2, 'account_id' => 1, 'username' => 'user', 'email' => 'user@test.com', 'password' => AuthComponent::password('test'), 'role' => 'user', 'password_token'=>'', 'password_token_expiry'=>'','created' => '2012-03-18 10:39:23', 'modified' => '2012-03-18 10:41:31'),
        );
        parent::init();
    }
}
```

The first testAction() is a POST, then the second one gets the "next" page - from there I do the asserts.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are mocking the entire Session component. This means all the session methods will return null. Remove the 'Session' key from `$this->generate()` and you should be good.

Comment: Thanks for the reply jeremyharris. But I am still getting the wrong results. Please see http://pastie.org/4110786

Comment: You shouldn't hash the password before passing it to the login action. That is done later by the authentication process. Also, you are not setting anything so `$this->vars` will always be empty. Headers won't when it passes. If you debug the session, you should see the "Invalid username..." message.

Comment: Thanks @jeremyharris. That makes sense. However, I have got a new problem, I now get "Invalid username/password" instead of "passing" the login. Please see updated code above.

Comment: That depends on your fixture data. Do you have your fixtures set up (with hashed passwords, just as your production database has)? Are they being imported (check the SQL log)?

Comment: Thanks so much @jeremyharris. I have successfully tested my login. Please see answer below.